Is there a way to change the size of ggplot text when knitting an R Markdown document on Mac so it matches Windows?
I am knitting an R Markdown file to a Microsoft Word document.  I have the size of all text within the ggplot plots set to the correct values so they output correctly when using a Windows machine.  However, when knitting the same file to a Microsoft Word document on a Mac machine, all of the text is very large and unreadable.
I have attempted to change the graphics device under Global Options in Rstudio and theme_update() in the setup chunk.  I am not using the same theme for all of the plots, so I don't believe that base_size() would be a solution here.

You need to set fig.height and fig.width in the chunk options - this controls the apparent size of the text relative to the size of the plot, and also set out.height and out.width to set the figure dimensions as drawn on the page. These should impel a constant text size across devices. Try as your chunk header {r myplot, fig.width = 5, fig.height = 4, out.height='400px', out.width='500px'}.
